# TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3. With pickle module

Tags: python

I have this task to do the following challenge and I am struggling at making it work.

"Janet is a tennis coach who tutors 6 young players who compete in local and national competitions. Three of them play in the under 11s and the other three play in the 11-16s.

Step 1. She would like a program that allows her to enter the names and positions and store the data so that she knows which age category they are in. Store the data in a file (USE PICKLE).

Step 2. Write a second program (or add this functionality to the first program) that reads the file and prints it on screen."

Under 11s                                11 to 16s
Jane-14th                                Henry-23rd
Grant-12th                               Jane-2nd
Lilly-17th                               Naomi-18th

"This is the code I have so far come up with. The error turns up at line 9. The error is:TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3. What I have written so far is shown below.

```
import pickle

print("These 3 names you are about to enter are in the Under 11s category")
Name1=input("Enter a name")
Name2=input("Enter a name")
Name3=input("Enter a name")

print("These 3 positions you are about to enter are in the Under 11s category")
Pos1=input("What position did",Name1,"come in?")
Pos2=input("What position did",Name2,"come in?")
Pos3=input("What position did",Name3,"come in?")

print("These 3 names you are about to enter are in the 11 to 16s category")
Name4=input("Enter a name")
Name5=input("Enter a name")
Name6=input("Enter a name")

print("These 3 positions you are about to enter are in the Under 11s category")
Pos4==input("What position did",Name4,"come in?")
Pos5==input("What position did",Name5,"come in?")
Pos6==input("What position did",Name6,"come in?")

a=[Name1,Pos1,Name2,Pos2,Name3,Pos3]
b=[Name4,Pos4,Name5,Pos5,Name6,Pos6]

myFile = open("Challenge 39.dat","wb")
pickle.dump(a,myFile)
pickle.dump(b,myFile)
myFile.close()

myFile =open("Challenge 39.dat","rb")
Under11s = pickle.load(myFile)
ElevenTo16s = pickle.load(myFile)
print(a)
print(b)
myFile.close()
```

I have checked other answers but it doesn't seem to work for me. If anyone could fix it or give an idea of what to do to fix it, it would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot pickle.load the same file object twice

Comment: What other answers did you check? Did you Google the exact error message you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3` says, the `input()` function only takes *one* argument. It cannot be sent multiple arguments like the `print()` function can. Create a single string to send, with `str.format()` or similar.

```
Pos1 = input("What position did {} come in?".format(Name1))
```